# Conditional Redirect on Login

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using forms authentication. My users are redirected to a page (written in web.config) when they login, but some of them may not have the privilages to access this default page. In this case, I want them to redirect to another page but RedirectFromLoginPage method always redirects to the default page in web.config. How do I make the users login, and then redirect to a page which depends on some criteria?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SetAuthCookie` allows you to issue the auth cookie but retain control over the navigation. After that method is called you can run your logic to do a typical ASP.NET redirect to wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mc.GetfaalUsers(mm.UserName.ToString())=="True")
{
    this.Page.ClientScript.
       RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", 
                                 "alert('این نام کاربری فعال نشده است');", false);
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
}
```