# asp.net change default login page

Tags: asp.net, authentication, web-config, authorization

I have a site where i added two separate login pages, one for users and another form admin then i used authorization in web.config **file to block access to the admin files**.

```
<system.web>
<authorization>
    <allow roles="Mod"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

and it work fine but the problem is it **redirects to the users login page instead of the admin's**.

so my question is there a **way to change the default login page**?

using asp.net 4.0

thanks.

Comment: possible dup! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36876/conditional-redirect-on-login

Comment: @Devjosh - in that question the problem was using RedirectFromLoginPage but here im using built in asp.net redirect and i require the use of two login pages.

Comment: Maybe I don't see some advantages of this solution but why do you need to login pages? Is admin login require some additional information? I have project with forms auth and urlMapping, it was impossible and I just made redirections my self, cause formauthentication calss is static and doesn't support overriding. You just need to control redirection on login page and on session start event.

Comment: @DenisAgarev - i tried manual redirects but my problem is that there is a lot of pages and if i try to add it to a master-page page load event it will go into an infinite loop, anyway thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need to add it to all pages. Just to Session_Start in global.asax and to login click on login page